# Get Pickling error while trying to create a table in GBQ using Python code

Tags: python, google-bigquery, pickle

I am new to Python and I was wondering whether someone can help me as I have searched Google and can't find a simple answer.

I have a code which runs a SQL query and puts the results in a new table in GBQ
my code is shown below:
when I run this I get the following error.

Is there an easy way to fix this error

> Pickle.PicklingError: Pickling client objects is explicitly not supported.
> Clients have non-trivial state that is local and unpickleable.

```
import time
from google.cloud import bigquery
from google.oauth2 import service_account

# prepare the BQ variables
project_id = 'myprojectid'
destination_dataset_id = 'datasetname'
destination_table_id = 'tablename'

path = 'path '
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(path)

bqclient = bigquery.Client(credentials= credentials,project=project_id)
#bqclient = bigquery.Client()



# Query Job configuration
query_job_config = bigquery.QueryJobConfig()

destinatination_dataset_ref = bqclient.dataset(destination_dataset_id).table(destination_table_id)

destination_table_ref = bqclient.dataset(destination_dataset_id).table(destination_table_id)

query_job_config.destination = destination_table_ref

#SQL Query 
sql_query = bqclient.query ("""
        select  programme from <project_id>.<dataset>.<table> Limit 2 """)

# Run the sql query
query_job = bqclient.query(sql_query, job_config=query_job_config)


#Waiting for the job to complete
while sql_query.state != 'Done' :
    time.sleep(3)
    sql_query.reload()
print(f'Query result is save to {destination_table_ref.dataset_id}.{destination_table_ref.table_id}')
```

Comment: I would suggest contacting Google support for them to look more information on your logs to investigate this error. https://cloud.google.com/contact